# How to add prefix to namespace declaration in axis wsdd file?

Tags: web-services, web-applications, namespaces, axis, xml-namespaces

Axis 1.4 based webservice.
The client sends following request :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:ns1="http://org.mysite.services/service/np">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ABC:createAction>
  <ABC:resourceID>MyResource</ABC:resourceID>
</ABC:createAction>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Error :

```
<soapenv:Fault>
 <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
 <faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix ”ABC” for element 
 “ABC:createAction” is not bound.
</faultstring>
```

server-config.wsdd has following configuration :

```
 <service name="MyService" provider="java:RPC" style="wrapped" use="literal">
 <namespace>http://webservices.mysite.org</namespace>
```

UPDATE:

How the proper client request should look in this context ?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the client, who should be specifying ABC as a namespace prefix for http://webservices.mysite.org.  Are you trying to fix the client or modify the server so the client works?

Comment: Thank you for replay , Ireeder !  You right client has changed . Currently I'm trying to fix the served side by fixing server-config.wsdd , but still have no idea how to do it. Both suggestions (to fix client or fix server ) are more then welcome , because currently I'm stuck  . Thank you in advance . Toren

Comment: Without seriously hacking the server side, you'll need to fix the client.  If it's sending an unspecified namespace prefix, none of the XML validation or parsing on the server side will accept the request.  Even if you managed to set the server-side prefix for http://webservices.mysite.org to "ABC", the client would need to define the namespace for prefix "ABC" on its end.  Were the client soap stubs also generated using Axis?

Comment: Thanks for replay. Client generated from C++ , for example : wsdl2h -v -N ABC -q ABC -o soap.h MySerivces.wsdl . Your help much appreciated .

Comment: and What need to be done for seriously hacking of the server side ? I see following plan : 1) check if need to add namespace prefix to server-config.wsdd 2) track soap messages with tcpdump , what else ?

Comment: You'd have to write your own XML parsing and validation which ignored invalid namespace problems.  Basically give up Axis or any other XML frameworks.  Not fun!

Comment: Ohhh ...  I prefer to fix client if so , as i understand all what client need is to fix namespace problem .